# crawler (of my own design) cannot fetch more than 10 urls

Tags: python, url, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, information-retrieval

I wrote a simple Python crawler to fetch urls from a website. Here is the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests as req

def get_soup(url):
    content = req.get(url).content
    return BeautifulSoup(content,'lxml')

def extract_links(url):
    soup = get_soup(url)
    a_tags = soup.find_all('a', class_="kkyou true-load-invoker")
    links  = set(a_tag.get('href') for a_tag in a_tags)
    return links

def set_of_links(url, size):

'''
breadth-first search for article hyperlinks
'''

seen = set()
active = extract_links(start_url)

while active:
    next_active = set()
    for item in active:
        for result in extract_links(item):
            if result not in seen:
                if len(seen) >= size:
                    break
                else:
                    seen.add(result)
                    next_active.add(result)
    active = next_active

    return seen
```

Essentially, I get a soup from a start url I specify, extract all urls within the start url that have class **kkyou true-load-invoker** and then I repeat the process in a breadth-first fashion for all urls I have collected. I stop this process when I have seen a certain number of urls.

Until a couple of weeks ago, I had no problem running this. I could specify any number of urls and it would fetch them for me. I just tried the exact same code today, and it only returns a maximum of 14 urls. For example, if I ask it to fetch me 50 urls, it will only fetch 10 and stop. Clearly, this cannot be a problem with the code because I changed nothing! I am wondering whether the page I am trying to crawl is using some mechanism to stop me from crawling an "excessive" number of pages. The page I am trying to crawl is [this](http://protagon.gr) (choose any article as a start url).

Any insights on this will be greatly appreciated! I am a complete novice in web crawling.

Comment: i got similar  error when trying to download a whole site with wget, the rest just get ignored. but resumed when i add some sleep between each fetch operation, might due to that the site you are crawling has some anti-bot config, just a possible reason:)

Comment: The problem is that `active`sometimes is an ampty set which evaluates to false and breaks your loop.

Comment: @t.m.adam that's not the case. just check the design of the page and you will see why. plus, that was not happening two weeks ago.

Comment: @JackWu interesting! I have never heard of this 'sleep' before. can you point to some resource where I can read more about it?

Comment: just google "wget download whole site", u could found parameter like -r or -m, the one that do sleep is -w , add some time.sleep(1) is easy, well, not quite likely to solve ur problem, could just give it a try.  there are existing crawler like pysipder or scrpy, also use request or bs4, might also check their idea

Comment: Did @JackWu's suggestion work for you, Orest? If so, please consider adding the answer yourself and accepting it. :)